# How to get content from an url by client ip address NOT server address

Tags: javascript, php

What I'm actually trying to do is getting content of an URL from another site there I want get the content by client ip address NOT server. Is there any way to do this?

Here I tried some how but, not succeed :/

```
<?php
$homepage = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

I'll accept if there is a way in javascript also.

Comment: What do you mean by _"get the content by client ip address NOT server"_? If you have a question, please spend time in articulating your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: MR @Thangadurai  when i'm getting content of for example google it's getting by server ip address which is something that don't want.

Comment: Am I the only one around here that doesn't quite understand what OP is trying to achieve? What content do you want to get from a regular user's computer?

Comment: @kerbholz .  I'm trying to get the **http://example.com/testm3u8?wmsAuthSign=code** using PHP get content 

as u can see that code at the end of url is changing by ip address and it's not working by server ip address. only claint ip :D

Comment: Assuming the client is a browser, since you can't run PHP in the browser, you can't do this with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
<?php
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];     
    $page_name = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];      
    $query_string = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];   
    $current_page = $page_name."?".$query_string; 
    echo $ip_address
?>
```

Comment: I want the to get the content of example.com by client ip address. :)